# How to print a single item of a list at specific key from dict list

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

Creating a list with 2 arrays, list contains one item from array `zz` and 1 one item from array `xtime`.

```
l = np.empty(len(yy), dtype=np.object)
for i in range(len(zz)):
    l[i] = zz[i], xtime[i]

print(l[:10])
```

output:

```
[(2, 2008) (1, 2008) (4, 395) (3, 395) (6, 1935) (5, 1935) (8, 3828)
 (7, 3828) (10, 4182) (9, 4182)]
```

Here I am creating a dict of lists (each key is a node containing to which node it is connected and time to get to that node).

```
for i in range(0,5):
    g.addEdge(yy[i], l[i])
```

Following is the dict list (is this a correct form of dict list?) and I want to get values like to which node 2 is connected (as it is connected to node 1). So to get that value if this dict list is in correct format.

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [(2, 2008)], 2: [(1, 2008)], 3: [(4, 395)], 4: [(3, 395)], 5: [(6, 1935)]})
```

Comment: What's the reason for using an object dtype array instead of a list?   Correct indentation.  Also don't use variables that you haven't at least described, if not actually defined.

Comment: What is the type of the `g` variable? Where is it being created?

Comment: l = np.empty(len(yy), dtype=list)
for i in range(len(zz)):
    l[i] =zz[i] , xtime[i]

Comment: @martineau 'g' is the object of class graph